# How to manage HP Array on MSA1000?

Tags: storage, hp

On the server I have two fiber channel in multipath that connected to MSA1000:

```
0b:00.0 Fibre Channel: Emulex Corporation Zephyr-X LightPulse Fibre Channel Host Adapter (rev 02)
0b:00.1 Fibre Channel: Emulex Corporation Zephyr-X LightPulse Fibre Channel Host Adapter (rev 02)
```

All works fine :) But how to manage HP Array on MSA1000? This is an old unsupported product. I've found documenation and install cpqacuxe, hpacucli and hpsmh (started service hpsmhd and  cpqacuxe -R). Now, web-server (as well as hpacucli) and tells that no controllers found.

```
# dmesg | grep cpq
cpqarray: Device 0x46 has been found at bus 5 dev 1 func 0
cpqarray: Finding drives on ida0 (Smart Array 431)
cpqarray ida/c0d0: blksz=512 nr_blks=860216490
```

Do I need ciss driver or smth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're very old now but we used to have one in a development rig and if I recall correctly you have to configure them over the serial port if you're moving from a fabric-based configuration to a direct-attached config as it sounds like you are. Only then will ACU or whatever see the controllers. Even then the Linux tools for setting this up are poor compared to the Windows versions. Another option worth looking at might be to boot up your server from a HP SmartStart DVD/.ISO - you could then go into the ACU GUI and see what you can see, if you expect to have a very static array configuration then you should be able to use that to get the job done and never need to use it again.

Comment: This is correct. The serial approach will work